# PyTest vs Unittest Framework (Testloader and LoadTestsFromTestCase methods)

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pytest, python-unittest

For web Automation testing we are using python /selenium /pycharm /pytest framework.

I have like 5 files(modules) and each file have nearly 10 tests each.
(i.e) total 5 x 10 = 50 test cases.

Now I am planning to run it via Jenkins and for that I have to give all these 5 files but my question is how can i run all 50 test cases from 5 files using just 1 file?

I am aware that using unittest framework, I can create one single file called for example Alltestsuite.py and pass in details of these 5 files by class name using inbuilt methods in unittest framework and it works fine (i.e)

```
tc1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(doctorsTest)
tc2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(engineersTest)
tc3 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(mechanicsTest)
tc4 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(plumbersTest)
tc5 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(buildersTest)
```

my question is (1) can the same be done or available in pytest framework?
(2) anything similar or alternative to TestLoader /loadTestsFromTestCase in pytest framework

Comment: No need for that in pytest. Read up on [test discovery in pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) - basically pytest will find the tests in all files.